# Does MongoCollection.forEach need to be thread safe?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

When using the MongoDB Async Java Driver:
Does the following callback need to use a AtomicInteger counter or would a normal int do the job?

```
Block<Document> theBlock = new Block<Document>() {
  AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
  @Override
   public void apply(final Document document) {
     counter.incrementAndGet();
   }
 };
SingleResultCallback<Void> callbackWhenFinished = ...

collection.find().forEach(theBlock, callbackWhenFinished);
```

Answer (score 3):

The only real difference between the `MongoDB Java API` and its `async` counterpart is that the methods of the latter are non-blocking and take callbacks as arguments. This means that what you receive in your callback is equivalent to what the method returns in the non-async API.

Here, you use the `find` method. It returns a "normal" iterable, so calling `forEach` on it will not result in multiple threads.

In other words, **you don't need an `AtomicInteger`**: your `apply` method is called sequentially, by the same thread.

---

If you still have doubts or need a "proof", you can do one of the following:

1. add a `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());` inside your block. You will see it is always performed by the same thread;
2. add a breakpoint inside your block, configured to stop only the thread. Once again, the breakpoint will block the whole code.